# Is it possible to type function with dynamic number of parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I'm now trying to type entity called Operators. It looks like this and as you can see has many commons. But there are some differences in values, for example callback function by `count` key. Sometimes it expects 1 number, sometimes 2.

```
const operatorEntities: Record<OperatorsKeys, OperatorValue> = {
  sin: {
    textForInput: "sin",
    onClick,
    type: UNARY_OPERATOR_TYPE,
    innerHtml: "sin",
    count: Math.sin,
    level: 3,
    className: "sinus btn btn-outline-primary",
  },
  cos: {
    textForInput: "cos",
    onClick,
    type: UNARY_OPERATOR_TYPE,
    innerHtml: "cos",
    level: 3,
    count: Math.cos,
    className: "sinus btn btn-outline-primary",
  },
  "!": {
    textForInput: "!",
    onClick,
    type: UNARY_OPERATOR_TYPE,
    innerHtml: "!n",
    level: 3,
    count: function factorialize(num): number {
      if (num < 0) return -1;
      else if (num == 0) return 1;
      else {
        return num * factorialize(num - 1);
      }
    },
    className: "factorial btn btn-outline-primary",
  },
  "+": {
    textForInput: "+",
    onClick,
    type: BINARY_OPERATOR_TYPE,
    innerHtml: "+",
    level: 1,
    count: (left, right) => left + right,
    className: " plus btn btn-outline-primary",
  },
  "-": {
    textForInput: "-",
    onClick,
    type: BINARY_OPERATOR_TYPE,
    innerHtml: "-",
    level: 1,
    count: (left, right) => left - right,
    className: "minus btn btn-outline-primary",
  }
}
```

So if I make type of the count function this way

```
type CountFunction = (operand1: number, operand2?: number) => number;
```

Then it will be the mistake in such a function

```
count: (a, b) => a + b;
```

Because b argument may be undefined. In this case I wanted to ask if there is any way to type function with 2 arguments and the second one should be optional? Or i just have to make 2 types for function with one and two arguments?

Comment: Since it seems you have a need to keep track of the number of arguments the functions expect, I'd suggest specifying both types of function separately and using a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) to distinguish between cases, as shown [in this Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WokyLW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, yes sir, could you please provide your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, it's not safe to assign a function of type `(o1: number, o2: number) => number` to a variable of type `(o1: number, o2?: number) => number`, because such a function expects `o2` to be a `number` and might explode when unknowingly dereferencing an `undefined` at runtime.  According to the [rules for function subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions),  `(o1: number, o2: number) => number` is a supertype of `(o1: number) => number`, so your `CountFunction` would just be

```
type CountFunction = (o1: number, o2: number) => number;
```

That might be surprising, but the TypeScript compiler takes the view that a function of the form `(o1: number) => number` will probably just ignore a second argument, and so it's harmless to allow the assignment.  So you can't make `o2` optional, but you can omit it altogether.  Such confusion between optional parameters and shortened parameter lists is common enough that it is [explicitly discussed in the TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters-in-callbacks).

---

So that's the answer to your question as asked, but it's not what you want, is it?  It will let your assignments succeed:

```
enum OperatorType {
    UNARY,
    BINARY
}
type OperatorThing = {
    type: OperatorType,
    count: (x: number, y: number) => number
}
const operatorEntities: Record<string, OperatorThing> = {
    sin: { type: OperatorType.UNARY, count: Math.sin, },
    cos: { type: OperatorType.UNARY, count: Math.cos, },
    "!": {
        type: OperatorType.UNARY, count: function factorialize(num): number {
            if (num < 0) return -1;
            else if (num == 0) return 1;
            else {
                return num * factorialize(num - 1);
            }
        },
    },
    "+": { type: OperatorType.BINARY, count: (left, right) => left + right, },
    "-": { type: OperatorType.BINARY, count: (left, right) => left - right, }
}
```

but when you try to actually call those `count` methods you'll find that the compiler now requires you to pass in a second argument no matter what, even if you check the `type` property:

```
Object.keys(operatorEntities).forEach(k => {
    const op = operatorEntities[k];
    if (op.type === OperatorType.UNARY) {
        op.count(1); // error!
        // ~~~~~~~~ <-- expected 2 arguments but got 1
    } else {
        op.count(2, 3);
    }
})
```

So it isn't very helpful to have a function type that represents the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the possible function types you have.  You want a way to *discriminate* among them.

---

My suggestion here is to keep your separate one- and two-argument function types, and define `OperatorThing` as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where the `type` property acts as a *discriminant* that can be used to determine which function type you have:

```
type OperatorThing =
    { type: OperatorType.UNARY, count: (o1: number) => number } |
    { type: OperatorType.BINARY, count: (o1: number, o2: number) => number }
```

The assignment of `operatorEntities` still succeeds, but now you can call functions with the right number of arguments:

```
Object.keys(operatorEntities).forEach(k => {
    const op = operatorEntities[k];
    if (op.type === OperatorType.UNARY) {
        op.count(1); // okay
    } else {
        op.count(2, 3); // okay
    }
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBlArjCAnAKgT0yQG8BYAKCUqQmDTCQHlMsQAXAe1wOVIqv4CqAOQCCAJQCaAGnL9+AIQCSoybKoBfcmsqtuSAMLs0wVgDFj8VgEt2wJAF4kACnYBGAFxJaYAEbYpSOwATJ7eflgAlA4AfF504QDcWnw6ekzYbJw4ABZWwADmDsTacrqYnuksHFyYMily8EYmnobGZhbWtkn1mmQljcBQrIHMmVgAoiZW1tCeYhCNWAAmADxDWHn5AZVjOZuxjrxyVFB5nkRIZRAVo9X4mAB0wuLSSI1tngCybNkPp8ABdR1Y6URpQc6Xbg3DJ3bhPFSvd7NJDfVi-MGA4EggBEAEJsecSiDIeVGLcsnDnpIAkjWJ4AGYdGx2ekIapWEAAGysAC8IE5vBFQvFsMV6sT+FZ6c5vEgVkgAAxRLAQVhoLB2AC0rm6EpBEE5UGQUpldAcjiVSBVao1SB1RL11ENPAdjqo1vVdllACokKzLJwOdy+QKzZq7RFdW6NK65EDY-HxVRsQBqAnEEnXMkwimPJQImlNOnOTkQemsAIbfLZVhReyxUvlpApq1WasVpCJ4nYzXpi5XaFVXMQB75l6Fj4lssdqs1usN6dIcOzju9fi9EoMHwAKwWrAeAGsIHgoC5yRMpjMoBEHvTOOMENknAeYmLiQMhiMiuxz5NrFeAG0DwAXSjY4TTPB4rnNRwdlhR4qQkKIjkdH8HlpJxXEjJAAHocOoLAsE4XFY34PCkAAPyo6iqLlTVwwgAAPTBLAgJYkCCJAQCwfI6BoVgoCQHw0GGfJ2GGVwEydI031QmB0KLJwggCABmSMExKdQImSDcyFASBYAQZAABErCgeABFkygaDNODhysuREKxY4x1UHpkn4aC7NwXICgcWN+yhbMhxqEcnLeItPBcDw4l8bB51i8JOyQAAfALM0HXY4VcxFIucNxhTirAAmCQrwgSsJRV0-gP2GH8cwvf8rFmJB5kWVZ1k2bZzz2AoDgc-h-ghAdgqyhCCwiydUV+f5MVjMFhqC7z7jCibaS+H4FKgOak0oPE+1IqgRuWyk1ryxlgEsZk-TZQMuV5flBTK0UUOjJAINleVLQ9W1tTA6MDRkj6zXsC1lVVT07X+t1AZdXbox+r0zV9f12XukNZXDLDocdNdcecuMCf4VM+wy0b4JHHKJ2RJxGxnNs51fOnm1bdsdu7XtFtJE682UcdJppunKwZ2smcXZcRcBTSPKoLdd0sQ9j1PeqQr-aZmuvW970fZ9X1ehpbE-H9v1-S8NaA0DYwgtDoNB2CetOl5kMOyg0Iw7HcPw9gDxAPApNhgaQTdxTlKQNSccoPHI+0vpY-UIA)